# Delete Windows Share 'History' "the folders shared below were previously shared"?

Tags: windows-registry, share

When trying to share a folder, if there have been previous shares on folders (which have since been removed), Windows will prompt: "the folders shared below were previously shared" and ask what you want to do with them.

Does anyone know how to remove those from the registry completely? These are no longer active shares, so they don't show up in computer management or any of the typical Windows Registry locations. I'd prefer if I remove a share that Windows just doesn't know anything about them anymore.

[Previous Shares Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMD2L.jpg)

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares

Comment: This key shows current shares, not shares that were made previously but no longer exist (have been removed). Windows appears to keep a history of removed shares. I just added a screen shot above. Sharing D:\[FOLDER]\sites\davecore -- it prompts that subfolders had shares in the past and asks what I want to do with those. Where does Windows store that history (so it even knows to ask) if the share has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

Already a few years old but came up first in my search results.
Had the same issue but found a solution.

When you get the Windows prompt: "The folders shown below were previously shared" and ask what you want to do with them.

Choose for the option "Change settings".

This will remove the non-existing entries for all sub folders.
You can test it afterwards by removing and adding your share again. The list of entries will then be empty.